# Jquery problema em tratar dados do ajax vindo como array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, array-multidimensional

Meu array retorna do php assim (post):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [O email digitado é invalido! Por favor insira um email correto.] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [O telefone digitado está num formato invalido por favor siga o modelo: (DDD) XXXX-XXXX] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Sua senha deve ser maior que 4 caracteres e menor que 20] => 1
        )

)
```

Meu objetivo é fazer com que o Jquery utilize o array principal para identificar a frase ex:

*1. O Email digitado é...
 2. O Telefone digitado está...
 3. Sua senha deve ser....*

E o array interno, da mensagem identifique o tipo de css que vou usar. 1 - erro grave, 2- erro comum, 3-acerto.
 Só que não sei como fazer. Quando tento usar um foreach, me deparo com um erro no lenght, que retorna undefined.
 Toda ajuda é bem vinda...

============ CODIGO PHP ================

```
<?php
$jq = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

if($jq['acao'] == 'cadastro'):
    unset($jq['acao']);
    require ('../_app/Models/Cadastro.class.php');
    require '../_app/Config.inc.php';

    $cadastra = new Cadastro;
    $cadastra->ExeCadastro($jq);

    if(!$cadastra->getResult()):
        print_r($cadastra->getError());
    else:
        print_r($cadastra->getResult());
    endif;
endif;
```

O PHP recebe do jquery os dados dos campos armazena via post na variavel jq e manda pra classe.

============== CLASSE DO PHP =====================

```
private function CheckData() {
    if (!Check::Email($this->Data['email'])):
        $this->Result = FALSE;
        $this->Error[] = ["O email digitado é invalido! Por favor insira um email correto." => 1];
    endif;
    if (!Check::Telefone($this->Data['telefone'])):
        $this->Error[] = ["O telefone digitado está num formato invalido por favor siga o modelo: (DDD) XXXX-XXXX" => 1];
        $this->Result = FALSE;
    endif;
    if (strlen($this->Data['senha']) < 5 || strlen($this->Data['senha']) >= 20):
        $this->Error[] = ["Sua senha deve ser maior que 4 caracteres e menor que 20" => 1];
        $this->Result = FALSE;
    endif;
}

private function CheckCadastro() {
    $CheckExistUser = new Read;
    $CheckExistUser->ExeRead('cadastro', "WHERE email = :e", "e={$this->Data['email']}");

    if ($CheckExistUser->getResult()):
        $this->Error[] = ["O email {$this->Data['email']} já está cadastrado no sistema. Se você for ... clique aqui. Se não tente um outro email" => 1];
        $this->Result = FALSE;
    endif;
}
```

A classe é maior um pouco mas, segue este principio. Se tiver erro nos dados que ela recebeu armazena no $this->Erro e não deixa proseguir o cadastro no banco de dados.
 Como deu pra ver no PHP eu recupero o erro pelo $cadastra->getErro, se tiver mando um print_f para imprimir a mensagem.
 Meu objetivo agora é tratar a mensagem que recebi para exibir pro cliente. De modo que o array principal seja o identificador da quantidade de erro e a atibuição interna da mensagem identifique o tipo, se for 1 é um erro,vou ver pelo numero o tipo e identificar qual css vou utilizar para mandar a mensagem final.

Comment: Você não deveria usar os valores como chaves.

Comment: Coloca seu código fonte tanto do PHP quanto jQuery, que facilita.

Comment: coloquei um trecho veja ai! :)

Comment: Você não deveria retornar os dados com um `print_r`. Usa um `json_encode`, que gera um objeto javascript. Tipo: `echo json_encode($cadastra->getResult())`

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o forEach.

```
   $.each(array, function( index, value ) {
         alert( index + ": " + value );
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Você tem acesso ao código PHP? A melhor (e mais simples) maneira para tratar esse dado é prepara-lo para o javascript utilizando a função `json_encode($array);`. Agora caso contrario vai ter que utilizar regular expression e vai perder performance e integridade neste dado.